# Eclipse deletes "problems/errors" as soon as I edit the file that had the error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a custom error Parser which detects some regex in the console output and highlights them as errors.
This works fine. However, lets say file1 has 20 errors, as soon as I edit and save file1, to fix one of the errors for example, the complete list of errors from file1 is deleted. And thus cannot navigate to them easily.

how can I disable that to have the errors/problem persist until the next build?

Comment: How are you showing them and trying to persist them now?

Comment: Sorry, I did not really get the question. I am showing them by simply applying a custom Error Parser. Once it detects the errors, it highlights them as Problems in the problems tab, console output, and editor itself.

Comment: Ok, and how are you making them appear in the Problems tab? Are you also using an editor of your own?

Comment: no, I wrote a regex error parser into eclipse.. thats standard eclipse capability